Combining three polygons and contour the edges
I am working on RNMapBox
And Now I Have 3 polygons which are adjacent to each other
polygons =
[
  [
    [78.36999594594597, 17.736575959425156],
    [78.37002594594598, 17.736575959425156],
    [78.37002594594598, 17.73660595942516],
    [78.36999594594597, 17.73660595942516],
    [78.36999594594597, 17.736575959425156],
  ],
  [
    [78.37002394150257, 17.736575959425156],
    [78.37005394150258, 17.736575959425156],
    [78.37005394150258, 17.73660595942516],
    [78.37002394150257, 17.73660595942516],
    [78.37002394150257, 17.736575959425156],
  ],
  [
    [78.36999594594597, 17.73654801721783],
    [78.37002594594598, 17.73654801721783],
    [78.37002594594598, 17.736578017217834],
    [78.36999594594597, 17.736578017217834],
    [78.36999594594597, 17.73654801721783],
  ],
];

Now I want to combine these polygons and contour the outer edges of the polygon and show as single polygon
I used convex hull , concave hull turf also but at the L shape I am getting the diagonal shape.
whatever the shape is I want to contour the all the outer edges of the polygons here my polygons are dynamically created.
Can anyone tell me how to do it.
